# MQL Query Help Required: Getting aliases of episodes from a season MID

Tags: freebase, mql

I am trying to capture 351  and their aliases of season - "/m/07mx74h", but when I am using my query it gives only not-null values, while I also need those records which are null. PFA query and let me know how can I get all results for 351 records.

Thanks in advance!

**MQL Query:**

[{
  "id": "/m/07mx74h",
  "/tv/tv_series_season/episodes": [{
    "limit": 1000,
    "mid": null,
    "name": null,
    "/common/topic/alias": [{
      "value": null
    }]
  }]
}]

Comment: tried this query... now this is giving all results i.e. 351, but I dont want "lang": "/lang/en" and "type": "/type/text" in other fileds, is it possible?

[{
  "id": "/m/07mx74h",
  "/tv/tv_series_season/episodes": [{
    "limit": 1000,
    "mid": null,
    "name": null,
    "/common/topic/alias": [{}]
  }]
}]


[{
  "id": "/m/07mx74h",
  "/tv/tv_series_season/episodes": [{
    "limit": 1000,
    "mid": null,
    "name": null,
    "/common/topic/alias": [{}]
  }]
}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but if the goal is to also include episodes which don't have an alias, you can use this:

```
[{
  "id": "/m/07mx74h",
  "/tv/tv_series_season/episodes": [{
    "limit": 1000,
    "mid": null,
    "name": null,
    "/common/topic/alias": []
  }]
}]
```

The inner text value is the default returned, so you don't need the inner curly braces.